# How could a software router be created on .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sockets, ports

How could I create a program which transparently forwards connections to new IP addresses/ports?

For example, if a client initiates a TCP connection an IP Address of 111.111.111.111 and TCP Port of 111, then the program could be configured to forward that and following packets IP/port 222.222.222.222:222.

By transparently, I mean:

- Minimal performance penalty
- No need to adjust the client or ultimate destination software/configuration (just like a Transparent Web Proxy does not require explicit settings in Browser to be set up)
- Deals as low-level as possible with the OS network layer

I'd like to do this with .NET, C#, and Windows. But I don't want to create a simple TCP proxy, for various but unspecified reasons. If this can't be done, that may be an acceptable answer in the absence of a possible solution.

Comment: That's not routing. What you're describing is a "port-bouncer" or TCP proxy. They're trivial to implement.

Comment: @Dai Thanks - Googling "TCP proxy" is yielding useful information.  Does this work: {1. Create a listening socket. 2. Receive bytes from incoming connections. 3. Open new socket to forwarding destination. 4. Send the bytes to the new socket.}?  My fear is that this trivial scheme wouldn't be transparent.

Comment: Although the essence of your question has a simpler candidate answer, an answer exists which more inline with your question's title and nature of your comment: https://bitbucket.org/merarischroeder/softrouter/wiki/Home [note: unfinished]. When someone connects to 111.111.111.111:111 the program (software running via a Winpcap 10Mbps device) could intercept such a packet - even if there is no TCP Listener on that port, and forward as you require. This would be transparent, calming your fear. Some Mods are overly zealous when it comes to closing questions, it's a tough job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one I wrote a few weeks ago for an experiment:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

namespace TcpTunnel {

public static class Program {

    public static void Main(String[] args) {

        if( args.Length != 3 ) {

            Console.WriteLine("<remoteAddress> <remotePort> <listenPort>");
            return;
        }

        ServerConfiguration config;

        try {

            config = new ServerConfiguration( args[0], args[1], args[2] );

        } catch(ArgumentException aex) {

            Console.WriteLine("<remoteAddress> <remotePort> <listenPort>");
            Console.WriteLine( aex.Message );
            return;
        }

        Thread serverThread = new Thread( ServerThread );
        serverThread.Start( config );

        Console.WriteLine("Enter \"q<enter>\" to stop program.");

        String line;
        while( (line = Console.ReadLine()).ToUpperInvariant() != "Q" );

        config.ServerSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        config.ServerSocket.Close();
    }

    private class ServerConfiguration {

        public IPAddress RemoteAddress;
        public UInt16    RemotePort;
        public UInt16    ListenPort;

        public ServerConfiguration(String remoteAddress, String remotePort, String listenPort) {

            RemoteAddress = IPAddress.Parse( remoteAddress );
            RemotePort    = UInt16   .Parse( remotePort, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
            ListenPort    = UInt16   .Parse( listenPort, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
        }

        public Boolean RunServer = true;

        public Socket  ServerSocket;
    }

    private static void ServerThread(Object configObj) {

        ServerConfiguration config = (ServerConfiguration)configObj;

        ///////////////////////////////////////
        // Setup  



        ///////////////////////////////////////
        // Wait for client

        Socket serverSocket = config.ServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Unspecified);

        serverSocket.Bind( new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Any, config.ListenPort ) );
        serverSocket.Listen(1);

        Console.WriteLine("Now listening for port {0}, will forward to {1}.", config.ListenPort, config.RemotePort);

        while( config.RunServer ) {

            Socket client = serverSocket.Accept();

            Thread clientThread = new Thread( ClientThread );
            clientThread.Start( new ClientContext() { Config = config, Client = client } );
        }

    }

    private class ClientContext {

        public ServerConfiguration Config;
        public Socket              Client;
    }

    private static void ClientThread(Object contextObj) {

        ClientContext context = (ClientContext)contextObj;

        Socket              client = context.Client;
        ServerConfiguration config = context.Config;

        ///////////////////////////////////////
        // Connect to remote server.

        IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint( config.RemoteAddress, config.RemotePort );

        Socket remote = new Socket( remoteEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Unspecified);

        remote.Connect( remoteEndPoint );

        ///////////////////////////////////////
        // Run tunnel.

        Console.WriteLine("Running tunnel.");

        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[4096];

        for(;;) {

            if( client.Available > 0 ) {

                Int32 count = client.Receive( buffer );
                if( count == 0 ) return;

                remote.Send( buffer, count, SocketFlags.None );
            }

            if( remote.Available > 0 ) {

                Int32 count = remote.Receive( buffer );
                if( count == 0 ) return;

                client.Send( buffer, count, SocketFlags.None );
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```